# Using sed to append string from regex pattern in the same file

Tags: perl, sed

I'm new to unix programming like sed, perl etc. I've searched and no result found match my case. I need to append substring from top line in the same file. My file content text.txt :

```
Name: sur.name.custom
Tel: xxx
Address: yyy
Website: www.site.com/id=
Name: sur.name.custom1
Tel: xxx
Address: yyy
Website: www.site.com/id=
```

I need to append every Name (sur.name.*) to every website on its block.
So Expected ouput:

```
Name: sur.name.custom
Tel: xxx
Address: yyy
Website: www.site.com/id=sur.name.custom
Name: sur.name.custom1
Tel: xxx
Address: yyy
Website: www.site.com/id=sur.name.custom1
```

I've tried the following sed command:

```
sed -n "/^Website:.*id=$/ s/$/sur.name..*/p" ./text.txt;
```

But sed returned: Website: www.site.com/id=sur.name.* same string I put.
I'm sure sed can append from regex pattern. I need both sed and perl if possible.

Comment: Why are there two stars around `sur.name.custom`? In your input file `text.txt` there are no stars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use awk for this? Assuming names doesn't contain spaces following command should work:

```
awk '$1=="Name:"{name=$2} $1=="Website:"{print $0 name;next} 1' file
```

Perl equivalent:

```
perl -pale'
   $F[0] eq "Name:"    and $name = $F[1];
   $F[0] eq "Website:" and $_ .= $name;
' file
```

(Line breaks may be removed.)

Comment: Work as expected in bash, how do write to file? and can you provide sed or perl since I need sed or perl. thanks alots!

Comment: @saun I don't know perl and sed is not the right tool for this task. to update the input file with this command's output you need to use a temporary file, like `awk ... file > tempfile && mv tempfile file`.

Comment: OK, I will look into awk and thanks for your fast replied.

Comment: @saun: not sure why you say you need `sed` or `perl`? is it because they have the `-i` (inplace) option? The answer provided is just the long hand version of what is happening in the background when you use the `-i` option. There is no space savings using `-i`, you always 2X the disk space of your original file in order to modify it. `sed` is only good for `s/str/rep/g' file` operations. Learn `awk` and fly. .... [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) is very good. You'll know a lot  when you have worked thru that. Good luck.

Comment: Perl version added to answer. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @ikegami thanks, does it print other lines too? to my ignorant eyes it seems like it doesn't

Comment: Oops! It does now :) I was basing my code on your `awk` command (rather than the OP's question), except I don't know `awk`. I guess I know what that `1` means now :)

Comment: Perl version worked. But perl -pi wont write to file. lol ask again sorry. Edited: Perl -pali -e to write to file.

Answer (score 3):

Here' a sed solution:

```
sed '/^Name:/{h;s/Name: *//;x;};/^Website:/{G;s/\n//;}' filename
```

Translation: If the line begins with `Name:`, save the name to the hold space; if the line starts with `Website:`, append the (latest) name from the holdspace.

Comment: Thanks your sed version working fine! But the above answer first and provide awk and perl to be fair I chose first answer as accepted. thanks for sharing your sed command!

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/^Name:/h;/^Website:/G;s/\nName: //' file` would be acceptable?

Comment: @potong: Yes, I considered that, but decided that the first way would be simpler-- but now that I see it written out, I think I prefer yours.